# Using the "te" form of Sugiru

Tags: grammar

I've been mulling over my sentence here and whether it's grammatically correct:

> 山が見えたら**遠きすぎて**行きました。
> Yama ga mietara tooki sugite ikimashita

I take it to mean "If you see the mountain (if it can be seen), it means you've gone too far."

My question is whether it's possible to use すぎて (sugite) to mean "[Verb] too [Adverb]." In this case, "go too far".

**Another example:**

> うるさすぎてしゃべっている。
> Urusasugite shabette iru.
> (You're chatting too loudly)

For the record, I'm aware that from context alone I can simply say "Urusasugiru" and the listener can infer that I'm referring to their talking, therefore omitting the need for another verb, but I still need to know for times where you need to be specific.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that shaberu is a godan verb. I added an extra 't' to your romaji. Just to clarify, in your pattern "[Verb] too [Adverb]", your adverb **includes** the sugite part, right? I ask because tooku can be an adverb in its own right, but urasai is an adjective. So I'm not clear whether you are trying to add sugiru to existing adverbs or just make an adverb using sugiru, or maybe both.　Or maybe tooki sugite was just a typo for toosugite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are possibly three ways to say `[Verb] too [Adverb]`:

1. [verb (-i)] すぎる

   > 行きすぎる
   > 食べすぎる
   > 笑いすぎる
2. [adjective] く/に [verb (-i)] すぎる

   > 遅く行きすぎる
   > 早く食べすぎる
   > 急に笑いすぎる
3. [verb (-u)] のが [adjective] すぎる

   > 行くのが遅すぎる
   > 食べるのが早すぎる
   > 笑うのが急すぎる

If you can paraphrase it simply with "V too much" or "over-V", you always should choose #1. Choice between #2 and #3 is somewhat subtle, but I think it depends on how much understandable even if you remove the verb part. For example, when you see a running man you can either say "He runs too fast!" or just "He is too fast!"; in this case, #3 (走るのが速すぎる) is more suitable.

So neither of your examples uses the form you suggested:

> If you see the mountain, you've gone too far.
> 山が見えたら行きすぎです。
>
> You're chatting too loudly.
> 話し声が大きいです。
> <sub>(うるさい certainly means "annoyingly loud" but saying this in the face of someone would sound like "shut up!")</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that, while I can see the logic in your thinking, there are a few things not quite right here.

To express the idea that one has gone too far, it is possible to say ikisugita いきすぎた. Sugiru すぎる is attached to the verb いく. Sugiru as an auxiliary verb means that something is done too much or to extremes. Therefore, going too far is ikisugiru いきすぎる

Tooi とおい, as an adjective, will combine with sugiru すぎる by losing the i: toosugiru とおすぎる. However, verbs, off the top of my head at least, cannot be used as an adverb in the way that you have attempted. Instead, toosugiru とおすぎる, would be used as an adjective to describe a location or object as being too far away.

Having said that, adjectives such as tooi とおい, chikai ちかい, urusai うるさい, are used with sugiru すぎる less often that you may imagine. Telling off a child for being too noisy? Urusai うるさい will suffice (urusasugiru うるさすぎる is unnecessary, and indeed may imply that a little urusai is okay but they have passed that and become too urusai). There are also other phrasings such as あまりにもうるさい.

E.g. あまりにもうるさくて、集中できない。
It's/You're so loud that I can't concentrate.

If you want to use the すぎる form of an adjective, then you could say something like

喋るのがうるさすぎる
Your talking is too loud.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I realize I misunderstood tooku to be a na verb instead of tooi with ku. In light of that, is it grammatically incorrect to say "toosugite iku" just to clarified that the walking is too far? Because without context, it could be in excess of other things. ikisugiru could mean too long, for example, not too far, and while context by itself solves this misunderstanding, I wanna know if there is a way to specify.

Generally speaking, is it possible to use "sugite" to affect a subsequent verb?

Comment: The short answer to your question is no. I think what you want to do is to use sugiru as an adverb to describe/modify the verb iku. However, sugiru is a verb, and when you attach it to an adjective the compound becomes a verb, and verbs cannot be used as adverbs in Japanese. If you connect the te form of sugiru to another verb, it becomes more like 'and' or 'because/so' like typical te form connection. This is one of those times where you will need to rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have written good, long detailed answers, so I will just add my opinions. Warning: I am not a native Japanese speaker; I just watch a lot of Japanese animations.

I do not believe that the form "遠きすぎて" is contemporary Japanese. I am not sure, maybe in some Mediaevel 文語. "遠き" is the old noun-connecting (i.e., placed before a noun) form for the adjective. すぎる is a verb, so...

Ah, I see. You took the adverbival form of the adjective 遠く、and added すぎる there. No, I do not think you can do that. Probably only a noun or a verb's connecting form can come before すぎる.

And about "うるさすぎて", I do not think "-すぎる" can be an adverbial phrase (like "too loudly"). You see, すぎる itself is a verb. So, changing it to its connecting form "すぎて" does not make it an adverb for the thing that comes after that. If you say "うるさすぎて", it only means "(because) it is  too loud,". That is, some kind of reason. For example, "うるさすぎて勉強ができません。". That means "It is too loud that I cannot study.", NOT "I cannot study too loudly".

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the grammar points:
～て行きます go and do something
～てきます going to do (and come back)
～て帰ります going to do while coming back

This should work with any other verb in a ～て declination form.